# How to switch off GIMP message on RawTherapee export?

Tags: 12.04, gimp

I'm using RawTherapee 4.0.11.0 and have GIMP defined as the external editor. Each time export an image from RT into GIMP 2.8.6 I get the following message from GIMP:

"Warning:
The image you are loading has 16 bits per channel. GIMP can only handle 8 bit, so it will be converted for you. Information will be lost because of this conversion."

Any ideas how to turn the warning off?

Answer (score 1):

Add an error console tab somewhere in the interface where it isn't in the way to suppress the warnings:

Windows -> Dockable Dialogs -> Error Console.

Error messages should now go to this window instead of popping up a requester. It can be repositioned like a normal tool window.

Found this info at: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/comp.graphics.apps.gimp/hZCukWA2OzU